# Exists, Read and Write in just one step

Tags: c#, file, file-handling

I'm trying to find out if a file exists, if it does, verify if the css style already exists, if not, write them at the end of the file ...

I'm doing all this already but in 3 steps:

Does the file exist?

```
FileInfo fi= new FileInfo(Path.Combine(rootPath, "DefaultStyles.css");
```

If it does, I use `TextReader` to get the contents

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    r = tr.ReadToEnd().Contains(".onebyonecard");
    tr.Close();
}
```

Then I write into it if style was not found

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    tw.Write(cssStyle);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one easy open / close, instead needed to open the file over and over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can open a single stream for read and write - but given that you're reading the whole file, I would personally just open it twice. Note that your current code will *overwrite* the file, not append to it.

I would personally use the static methods in the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) class:

```
// Elide this into the "if" condition if you want. I've separated it out here,
// but obviously it makes no difference.
bool present = File.Exists(path) &&
               File.ReadAllText(path).Contains(".onebyonecard);
if (!present)
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, cssStyle);
}
```

This is simpler than having a read/write stream and creating both a `TextReader` and a `TextWriter` over it.

A couple of notes:

- By separating the file access, there *is* a slight risk of a race condition. We could open the file, read the contents, then it could be updated while we decide what to do next. Likewise the file could exist when we perform the check, but then be deleted before it's read. In most applications this risk is so slight as to be irrelevant - only you can say for sure.
- The code above could still throw an exception, if the file exists but can't be read/written by the relevant user, or is in use by another process. Normal exception handling style applies - decide to what extent you think you can actually recover from such situations, and act appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you are using `ReadToEnd()` you might as well use:

```
if (!File.Exists(file) || !File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(".onebyonecard"))
    File.AppendAllText(file, cssStyle);
```

but this still opens it twice. There are APIs that would allow it to be opened once only, but those are binary APIs (`Stream` etc) - which will *work*, but are probably overkill for your scenario.

Comment: I don't think you mean AppendText :)

Comment: @Jon darn; I *knew* compilers were there for a reason

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(file);
r = tr.ReadToEnd().Contains(".onebyonecard");
tr.Close();
tr.Dispose ();
}
catch { //File is not exists or is used by another application
}
```

Comment: You should use `using` statements instead of manually closing. You also haven't answered the question - currently you're just showing a *worse* version of what the OP is already doing.